# Selenium switch a period sign with a hebrew letter

Tags: java, selenium, sendkeys

Lately iv'e been working on a small automation framework and I run into a wierd problem. Everytime I run sendkeys fuction and sending a String that contains a period sign (".") - it is switching into "ץ", a Hebrew letter. My keybord is in Hebrew and English as well. Every other English letter or sign is working properly.I tried this in couple of websites, but it seems like there is a problem with period sign spesificlly.

A friend of mine tried running the same code at his computer and it worked normally.

I'm using selenium in java 13.2, in Windows 10. 
Tried switching form java 13 to java 8 through Build path tab, and removing all of selenium jars and reaplly them. None of these worked.

I will mention that I just installed Java in my computer, and never had this problem in any other device before.

[Here you can see my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGscU.png), [and here you can see how it look in google search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74utf.png)

> ```
>   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
>     driver.get("https://google.com");
>     driver.manage().window().maximize();
>     driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(".......... ,;'/!`<>abc123");
> ```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
I’ve changed my Windows display language to English and it solved the problem.